# Spring Bean overriding issue with Autowire 'byType'

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, autowired, overriding

I have one bean Name "MasterService" that has the attribute autowired="byType". In that bean I have one property as 
   AccountService accountService;
And I have registered implementation of this bean as "DefaultAccountService". Now somebody wants to extends 'DefaultAccountService' and create 'CustomAccountService'. and also register but during initialization of "MasterService" getting the exception that 2 beans are there for AccountService [DefaultAccountService and CustomAccountService]. 
we dont know how to resolve this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need the @Qualifier annotation

see this example:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-autowiring-qualifier-example/

in your case, it would be:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("customAccountService")
private  AccountService accountService;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override the default autowiring I think it's clearer if you manually wire that specific service, so maintainers know at first sight that in that case the default is *not* used:

```
<bean id="masterService" ... autowired="byType">
    <property name="accountService" ref="customAccountService"/>
</bean>
```

If you just don't want to manually wire anything, Kent's answer will do.